# R. Use frequency of a correlation to set dot size in plot

Tags: r, plot

Is it possible to use the frequency of a correlationn to set the cex value in a plot?
e.g. using mtcars. The correlation between cyl and carb.
table:

```
    cyl
carb 4 6 8
   1 5 2 0
   2 6 0 4
   3 0 0 3
   4 0 4 6
   6 0 1 0
   8 0 0 1
```

How can I use the values (e.g. 1 for 8 carb & 8 cyl) to set the size of the dots in an R?

The code is quite simple (I'm only new)

```
plot(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$carb,
    pch = 20,
    bty = "L",
    cex = what goes here????,
    col = carb.col[cyl],
    lines(lowess(cyl, carb),
    col = "red", lwd = 3)
)
```

Comment: How are you drawing the plot? Are you plotting the correlation matrix or something else? Share you plot code and we can help.

Comment: The code is quite simple
`
plot(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$carb,
     pch = 20,
     bty = "L",
     cex = what goes here????,
     col = carb.col[cyl],
     lines(lowess(cyl, carb), col = "red", lwd = 3)
     )
`

Comment: So, you want the size of the points to correspond to the number of cars in the point?

Comment: yes! :) that is it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer `ggplot`, but here's a `base` solution:

```
dat = data.frame(with(mtcars, table(cyl, carb)))
dat = subset(dat, Freq > 0)
dat[] = lapply(dat, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))

plot(dat$cyl, dat$carb,
    pch = 20,
    bty = "L",
    cex = dat$Freq,
    #col = carb.col[cyl],
    lines(lowess(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$carb),
    col = "red", lwd = 3)
)
```

[image]

If you wanted to use the code more generally, you'd probably want to scale the `cex` so it has a maximum size...

Comment: Okay, so I have to use a function to create a subset.
Thank you ever so much. That's absolutely brilliant! So much to learn!
And I do need to learn ggplot as well.

Comment: Yeah, `plot` can't really do anything but what you give it. You want sizes based on counts? Gotta calculate the counts. I'd strongly recommend `ggplot` though, once you get the core concepts it's much easier and nicer than `base`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fully reproducible ggplot solution:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(subset(reshape2::melt(table(mtcars$carb, mtcars$cyl)), value > 0)) + 
  geom_point(aes(Var1, Var2, size = value)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(4, 6, 8), name = "cyl") + 
  scale_x_continuous(name = "carb") + 
  scale_size(range = c(2, 8)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Filtering out the 0s might be nice.